# Obter retorno JSON de URL em VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Desejo acessar a URL ("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/usd-brl") para buscar o campo ask do json.

Como faço a requisição à URL e obtenho o valor desejado em uma variável?

Tentei algo como:

```
Dim json As String = GetWebPageText("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/usd-brl")



Private Function GetWebPageText(ByVal url As String) As String

    Try
        Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
        Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Return New StreamReader(Request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Deu certo ... ???

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado @VirgilioNovic pela clareza no exemplo e pela disposição!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instale o pacote pelo [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/): [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) ou via *Package Manager*:

> ***PM>*** *Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json*

e escreva o seguinte código para converter o texto `json` para objeto `Data`

***Classe*** *Data*:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class Data    
  Public Property Code As String    
  Public Property Codein As String    
  Public Property Name As String    
  Public Property High As Decimal    
  Public Property Low As Decimal    
  Public Property VarBid As Decimal    
  Public Property PctChange As Decimal    
  Public Property Bid As Decimal    
  Public Property Ask As Decimal    
  Public Property Timestamp As String    
  <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("create_date")>
  Public Property Createdate As Date
End Class
```

***Código de conversão***:

```
Private Function GetData(ByVal json As String) As Data
    Dim items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Data))(json)
    Return items(0)
End Function
```

***Código final***:

```
 Dim json As String = GetWebPageText("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/usd-brl")
 Dim data As Data = GetData(json)
 Dim ask As Decimal = data.Ask
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolveu adicionando a seguinte linha antes de fazer a chamada:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```